# Stop slideshow when element has class

Tags: javascript, jquery, unslider

I'm using [Unlsider](http://unslider.com/) slideshow plugin . i want to stop sliding when overlay is **ON** .

there is function in unslider called `data.stop();` , how can i call this when overlay has `open` class .

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zq8vm/169/)

```
$(function() {
    $('.banner').unslider();
    $("button").click(function(){
    $(".overlay").toggleClass("open");

});
});
```

thanks

Comment: Stopping the slider in the button click, does not help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need some kind of construction like I did:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zq8vm/170/

```
$(function() {
    var TheBanner=$('.banner').unslider();
    data = TheBanner.data('unslider');
    $("button").click(function(){
    $(".overlay").toggleClass("open");
       data.stop();
    });
});
```